# How to reset values from EnumFormType in Camunda?

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I have a problem with Camunda BMPN. In the diagram in the picture "example.bmpn" user task has form field which has ID science_area and it's an enum type. I want to get form field for science_area and add data into that enum from the database. 
The problem is because in EnumFormType data remain and every time when going into controller bellow 
old values ​​are joined by new ones.

[example.bpmn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLxZb.png)

Sample of code is below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form/{processInstanceId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<FormFieldsDto> getSciencePaperForm(@PathVariable("processInstanceId") String processInstanceId){
    ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).singleResult();
    Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).singleResult();
    TaskFormData tfd = formService.getTaskFormData(task.getId());
    List<FormField> properties = tfd.getFormFields();
    Magazine magazine = magazineService.findByName((String)runtimeService.getVariable(processInstanceId,"magazineName"));
    List<ScienceField> scienceFields = magazine.getScienceFields();
    for(FormField field : properties){
        if(field.getId().equals("science_area")){
            EnumFormType enumType = (EnumFormType) field.getType();
            for(ScienceField scienceField: scienceFields){
                enumType.getValues().put(scienceField.getName(), scienceField.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new FormFieldsDto(task.getId(), pi.getId(), properties), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Actually I've cast EnumFormType into Map, and then clear the content. This is part of the code that I changed.

```
   for(FormField field : properties){
        if(field.getId().equals("casopis")){
            Map<String, String> enumType = ((EnumFormType) field.getType()).getValues();
            enumType.clear();
            for(MagazineDTO magazineDTO: magazines){
                enumType.put(magazineDTO.getName(), magazineDTO.getName());

            }
            break;
        }
    }
```